# App Crashing when using word interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

When I try to export a .doc file on Win 8, the app crashes and returns this error, plus, it opens 2 savedialogs the expected one and another with the name of the source .doc file to be saved as a copy.

Here is the error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): O comando falhou
   em Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs(Object& FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePassword, Object& ReadOnlyRecommended, Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object& SaveNativePictureFormat, Object& SaveFormsData, Object& SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding, Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object& AllowSubstitutions, Object& LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks)
   em cadastramento.funcionarios.CreateWordDocument(Object fileName, Object saveAs) na C:\Users\Blind\Desktop\projeto\01cadastramento atual\cadastramento\funcionarios.cs:linha 949
   em cadastramento.funcionarios.button9_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Users\Blind\Desktop\projeto\01cadastramento atual\cadastramento\funcionarios.cs:linha 523
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

the referenced lines are:

```
          CreateWordDocument(caminho, "");    //523

  aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing); //949
```

The form word part code, was implemented from various sources and I tried till make it worj, so I don't have a clue on why it's giving this error msg.

The expected way it should work is to copy the  source file and save a new one with all text replaced and using savedialog.

Everything seems to work just fine on Win 7.

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var AssemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var caminho = "" + AssemblyPath + "\\Resources\\FICHAREG.doc";

        CreateWordDocument(caminho, "");
    }

    private void CreateWordDocument(object fileName,
        object saveAs)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0 && dataGridView1.Rows != null)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            string vIDg = (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            DataGridViewRow row2 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            string vIDg2 = (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());



        //Set Missing Value parameter - used to represent
        // a missing value when calling methods through
        // interop.
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //Setup the Word.Application class.
        Word.Application wordApp =
            new Word.Application();

        //Setup our Word.Document class we'll use.
        Word.Document aDoc = null;

        // Check to see that file exists
        if (File.Exists((string)fileName))
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;

            //Set Word to be not visible.
            wordApp.Visible = false;

            //Open the word document
            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
                ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing);






            // Activate the document
            aDoc.Activate();

            // Find Place Holders and Replace them with Values.



            string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE (id = @id)";
            SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = vIDg;
            SqlCeDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    string nomefuncs = myReader.GetString(1);
                    var nomefunc = nomefuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nomefunc$$", "" + nomefunc + "");

                    string numordems = myReader.GetString(82);
                    var numordem = numordems.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$numordem$$", "" + numordem + "");

                    string nummatriculas = myReader.GetString(83);
                    var nummatricula = nummatriculas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nummatricula$$", "" + nummatricula + "");

                    string nomepaifuncs = myReader.GetString(2);
                    var nomepaifunc = nomepaifuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nomepaifunc$$", "" + nomepaifunc + "");

                    string nomemaefuncs = myReader.GetString(3);
                    var nomemaefunc = nomemaefuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nomemaefunc$$", "" + nomemaefunc + "");

                    string paifuncnacios = myReader.GetString(4);
                    var paifuncnacio = paifuncnacios.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$paifuncnacio$$", "" + paifuncnacio + "");

                    string maefuncnacios = myReader.GetString(5);
                    var maefuncnacio = maefuncnacios.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$maefuncnacio$$", "" + maefuncnacio + "");

                    DateTime datanascs = myReader.GetDateTime(6);
                    var datanasc = datanascs.ToShortDateString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$datanasc$$", "" + datanasc + "");

                    string idades = myReader.GetString(88);
                    var idade = idades.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$idade$$", "" + idade + "");

                    string funcnacios = myReader.GetString(7);
                    var funcnacio = funcnacios.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$funcnacio$$", "" + funcnacio + "");

                    string estadocivils = myReader.GetString(8);
                    var estadocivil = estadocivils.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$estadocivil$$", "" + estadocivil + "");

                    string localnascs = myReader.GetString(9);
                    var localnasc = localnascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$localnasc$$", "" + localnasc + "");

                    string ufnascs = myReader.GetString(10);
                    var ufnasc = ufnascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$ufnasc$$", "" + ufnasc + "");

                    string rgs = myReader.GetString(11);
                    var rg = rgs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$rg$$", "" + rg + "");

                    string ctpssa = myReader.GetString(12);
                    var ctps = ctpssa.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$ctps$$", "" + ctps + "");

                    string ctpsss = myReader.GetString(13);
                    var ctpss = ctpsss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$ctpss$$", "" + ctpss + "");

                    string reservistas = myReader.GetString(14);
                    var reservista = reservistas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$reservista$$", "" + reservista + "");

                    string catreservistas = myReader.GetString(15);
                    var catreservista = catreservistas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$catreservista$$", "" + catreservista + "");

                    string cpfs = myReader.GetString(16);
                    var cpf = cpfs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$cpf$$", "" + cpf + "");

                    string tituloeleitors = myReader.GetString(17);
                    var tituloeleitor = tituloeleitors.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$tituloeleitor$$", "" + tituloeleitor + "");

                    string carteirasaudes = myReader.GetString(18);
                    var carteirasaude = carteirasaudes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$carteirasaude$$", "" + carteirasaude + "");

                    string cbos = myReader.GetString(19);
                    var cbo = cbos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$cbo$$", "" + cbo + "");

                    string cartmod19s = myReader.GetString(20);
                    var cartmod19 = cartmod19s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$cartmod19$$", "" + cartmod19 + "");

                    string casadobrasileiros = myReader.GetString(21);
                    var casadobrasileiro = casadobrasileiros.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$casadobrasileiro$$", "" + casadobrasileiro + "");

                    string naturalizados = myReader.GetString(22);
                    var naturalizado = naturalizados.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$naturalizado$$", "" + naturalizado + "");

                    string filhosbrasileiross = myReader.GetString(23);
                    var filhosbrasileiros = filhosbrasileiross.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$filhosbrasileiros$$", "" + filhosbrasileiros + "");

                    string datachegadabrasils = myReader.GetString(25);
                    var datachegadabrasil = datachegadabrasils.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$datachegadabrasil$$", "" + datachegadabrasil + "");

                    string nregistrogerals = myReader.GetString(26);
                    var nregistrogeral = nregistrogerals.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nregistrogeral$$", "" + nregistrogeral + "");

                    string nomeconjuges = myReader.GetString(27);
                    var nomeconjuge = nomeconjuges.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nomeconjuge$$", "" + nomeconjuge + "");

                    string quantosfilhoss = myReader.GetString(24);
                    var quantosfilhos = quantosfilhoss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$quantosfilhos$$", "" + quantosfilhos + "");

                    string enderecos = myReader.GetString(28);
                    var endereco = enderecos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$endereco$$", "" + endereco + "");

                    string mudancaenderecos = myReader.GetString(29);
                    var mudancaendereco = nregistrogerals.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$mudancaendereco$$", "" + mudancaendereco + "");

                    string corfuncs = myReader.GetString(70);
                    var corfunc = corfuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$corfunc$$", "" + corfunc + "");

                    string alturafuncs = myReader.GetString(71);
                    var alturafunc = alturafuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$alturafunc$$", "" + alturafunc + "");


                    string pesofuncs = myReader.GetString(72);
                    var pesofunc = pesofuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$pesofunc$$", "" + pesofunc + "");

                    string cabelosfuncs = myReader.GetString(73);
                    var cabelofunc = cabelosfuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$cabelosfunc$$", "" + cabelofunc + "");

                    string olhosfuncs = myReader.GetString(74);
                    var olhosfunc = olhosfuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$olhosfunc$$", "" + olhosfunc + "");

                    string sinaisfuncs = myReader.GetString(75);
                    var sinaisfunc = sinaisfuncs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$sinaisfunc$$", "" + sinaisfunc + "");


                    string dependente1s = myReader.GetString(30);
                    var dependente1 = dependente1s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente1$$", "" + dependente1 + "");

                    string dependente2s = myReader.GetString(33);
                    var dependente2 = dependente2s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente2$$", "" + dependente2 + "");

                    string dependente3s = myReader.GetString(36);
                    var dependente3 = dependente3s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente3$$", "" + dependente3 + "");

                    string dependente4s = myReader.GetString(39);
                    var dependente4 = dependente4s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente4$$", "" + dependente4 + "");

                    string dependente5s = myReader.GetString(42);
                    var dependente5 = dependente5s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente5$$", "" + dependente5 + "");


                    string dependente6s = myReader.GetString(45);
                    var dependente6 = dependente6s.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente6$$", "" + dependente6 + "");

                    string dependente1parentes = myReader.GetString(31);
                    var depentende1parente = dependente1parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente1parente$$", "" + depentende1parente + "");

                    string dependente2parentes = myReader.GetString(34);
                    var dependente2parente = dependente2parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente2parente$$", "" + dependente2parente + "");

                    string dependente3parentes = myReader.GetString(37);
                    var dependente3parente = dependente3parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente3parente$$", "" + dependente3parente + "");

                    string dependente4parentes = myReader.GetString(40);
                    var dependente4parente = dependente4parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente4parente$$", "" + dependente4parente + "");

                    string dependente5parentes = myReader.GetString(43);
                    var dependente5parente = dependente5parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente5parente$$", "" + dependente5parente + "");

                    string dependente6parentes = myReader.GetString(46);
                    var dependente6parente = dependente6parentes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente6parente$$", "" + dependente6parente + "");

                    string dependente1nascs = myReader.GetString(32);
                    var dependente1nasc = dependente1nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente1nasc$$", "" + dependente1nasc + "");

                    string dependente2nascs = myReader.GetString(35);
                    var dependente2nasc = dependente2nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente2nasc$$", "" + dependente2nasc + "");

                    string dependente3nascs = myReader.GetString(38);
                    var dependente3nasc = dependente3nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente3nasc$$", "" + dependente3nasc + "");

                    string dependente4nascs = myReader.GetString(41);
                    var dependente4nasc = dependente4nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente4nasc$$", "" + dependente4nasc + "");

                    string dependente5nascs = myReader.GetString(44);
                    var dependente5nasc = dependente5nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente5nasc$$", "" + dependente5nasc + "");

                    string dependente6nascs = myReader.GetString(47);
                    var dependente6nasc = dependente6nascs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dependente6nasc$$", "" + dependente6nasc + "");

                    string datacadpiss = myReader.GetString(48);
                    var datacadpis = datacadpiss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$datacadpis$$", "" + datacadpis + "");

                    string piss = myReader.GetString(49);
                    var pis = piss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$pis$$", "" + pis + "");

                    string nobancopiss = myReader.GetString(50);
                    var nobancopis = nobancopiss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$nobancopis$$", "" + nobancopis + "");

                    string endpiss = myReader.GetString(51);
                    var endpis = endpiss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$endpis$$", "" + endpis + "");

                    string bancopiss = myReader.GetString(52);
                    var bancopis = bancopiss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$bancopis$$", "" + bancopis + "");

                    string agpiss = myReader.GetString(53);
                    var agpis = agpiss.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$agpis$$", "" + agpis + "");

                    DateTime dataentradas = myReader.GetDateTime(54);
                    var dataentrada = dataentradas.ToShortDateString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dataentrada$$", "" + dataentrada + "");

                    DateTime dataregs = myReader.GetDateTime(55);
                    var datareg = dataregs.ToShortDateString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$datareg$$", "" + datareg + "");

                    string ocupacaos = myReader.GetString(56);
                    var ocupacao = ocupacaos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$ocupacao$$", "" + ocupacao + "");

                    string secaos = myReader.GetString(57);
                    var secao = secaos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$secao$$", "" + secao + "");

                    string salarioinicials = myReader.GetString(58);
                    var salarioinicial = salarioinicials.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$salarioinicial$$", "" + salarioinicial + "");

                    string comissoess = myReader.GetString(59);
                    var comissoes = comissoess.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$comissoes$$", "" + comissoes + "");

                    string tarefas = myReader.GetString(60);
                    var tarefa = tarefas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$tarefa$$", "" + tarefa + "");

                    string formapagamentos = myReader.GetString(61);
                    var formapagamento = formapagamentos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$formapagamento$$", "" + formapagamento + "");

                    string eoptantes = myReader.GetString(62);
                    var eoptante = eoptantes.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$eoptante$$", "" + eoptante + "");

                    DateTime dataopcaos = myReader.GetDateTime(63);
                    var dataopcao = dataopcaos.ToShortDateString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dataopcao$$", "" + dataopcao + "");

                    DateTime dataretratacaos = myReader.GetDateTime(64);
                    var dataretratacao = dataretratacaos.ToShortDateString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dataretratacao$$", "" + dataretratacao + "");

                    string bancodepositarios = myReader.GetString(69);
                    var bancodepositario = bancodepositarios.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$bancodepositario$$", "" + bancodepositario + "");

                    string hentradas = myReader.GetString(65);
                    var hentrada = hentradas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$hentrada$$", "" + hentrada + "");


                    string halmocos = myReader.GetString(66);
                    var halmoco = halmocos.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$halmoco$$", "" + halmoco + "");


                    string hsaidas = myReader.GetString(67);
                    var hsaida = hsaidas.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$hsaida$$", "" + hsaida + "");


                    string dsrs = myReader.GetString(68);
                    var dsr = dsrs.ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$dsr$$", "" + dsr + "");


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }







        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo faltando.");
            return;
        }


        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Documento do Word|*.doc";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Salvar";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "FICHA DE REGISTRO "+ vIDg2 +"";
        if (DialogResult.OK == saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
        {
            string docName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (docName.Length > 0)
            {


                saveAs = (object)docName;
                //Save the document as the correct file name.
                aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);





            }
        }


        //Close the document - you have to do this.
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)aDoc).Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        MessageBox.Show("File created.");

    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não há elementos para editar.", "Não há elementos para editar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

            this.funcionariosTableAdapter.Fill(this.cadastramentodbDataSet.Funcionarios);

            string constringF = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
            string QueryF = "SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE (status = @status and  idsetor = @idsetor and idempresa = @idempresa) ";

            SqlCeConnection conDataBaseF = new SqlCeConnection(constringF);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBaseF = new SqlCeCommand(QueryF, conDataBaseF);
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@idsetor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@idempresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
            try
            {


                SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBaseF;


                System.Data.DataTable dbdatasetF = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdatasetF);
                BindingSource bSourceF = new BindingSource();

                bSourceF.DataSource = dbdatasetF;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSourceF;
                sda.Update(dbdatasetF);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }



        }




    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is simply a helper method to find/replace 
    /// text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WordApp">Word Application to use</param>
    /// <param name="findText">Text to find</param>
    /// <param name="replaceWithText">Replacement text</param>
    private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application WordApp,
                                object findText,
                                object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
            ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
            ref nmatchAllWordForms, ref forward,
            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
            ref replace, ref matchKashida,
            ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza,
            ref matchControl);
    }
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Word? Is it the same on both systems? Does the Windows 8 system have any security constraints on the target folder? If it is Word 2010 or later (I think!), have you tried SaveAs2 instead of SaveAs? It may also be worth identifying which parameter of SaveAs/SaveAs2 specifies the document type and ensure that it corresponds to the ".doc" extension.

Comment: What is the actual file name passed into the SaveAs method? Make sure it doesn't contain any invalid characters and that the file location it writable.

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't, it only have A-Z uppercase characters.

The code I posted is all messed up, I didn't checked it correctely.

I'm currently trying something more clean. I just put all conditions on the button and then send it to the word part if every condition is met. I found out that on my developing PC I got Office2013, and the test machine it is 2007. I tested on another Office 2007 machine with Win 7 and it returned the same error when I set SaveAs() to SaveAs2(). What the difference from one to another?
I'll test the new code tomorrow on the problematic machine and post the result

Comment: I was having too much trouble with Word Interop so I moved on to DocX.

The library is a lot better and I don't have to deal with office issues and DocX support serverside .docx handling while Office Interop not. Will Edit the main question with the new code. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Please don't overwrite a question with a solution - as helpful as the intent is, the community regards that as destructive here. I've moved the answer to the answer space below, and have rolled back to your earlier version.

Comment: So when in the case of finding a better/another/better fiting for the ocasion/ should I add it as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I was just having too much trouble with the wholde Word Interop stuff, so I moved to DocX and it worked better and faster.

I'm posting the code, so anyone interested will have access to it. A Lot simpler than Office Interop.

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0 && dataGridView1.Rows != null)
            {        

                        Createe();              
        }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não há elementos para gerar a ficha de registro.", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

            this.funcionariosTableAdapter.Fill(this.cadastramentodbDataSet.Funcionarios);

            string constringF = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
            string QueryF = "SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE (status = @status and  idsetor = @idsetor and idempresa = @idempresa) ";

            SqlCeConnection conDataBaseF = new SqlCeConnection(constringF);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBaseF = new SqlCeCommand(QueryF, conDataBaseF);
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@idsetor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@idempresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
            try
            {


                SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBaseF;


                System.Data.DataTable dbdatasetF = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdatasetF);
                BindingSource bSourceF = new BindingSource();

                bSourceF.DataSource = dbdatasetF;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSourceF;
                sda.Update(dbdatasetF);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }



        }
    }


    public void Createe()
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        string vIDg = (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        DataGridViewRow row2 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        string vIDg2 = (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Documento do Word|*.docx";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Salvar";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "FICHA DE REGISTRO " + vIDg2 + "";
        if (DialogResult.OK == saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
        {
            string OutputFile = saveFileDialog1.FileName;



            if (OutputFile.Length > 0)
            {

                var AssemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                var caminho = "" + AssemblyPath + "\\Resources\\FICHAREG2.docx";

                using (DocX document = DocX.Load(caminho))
                {
                    // Replace text in this document.

                    string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
                    string Query = "SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE (id = @id)";
                    SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
                    SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                    cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = vIDg;
                    SqlCeDataReader myReader;
                    try
                    {
                        conDataBase.Open();
                        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {

                            string nomefuncs = myReader.GetString(1);
                            var nomefunc = nomefuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nomefunc$$", "" + nomefunc + "");

                            string numordems = myReader.GetString(82);
                            var numordem = numordems.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$numordem$$", "" + numordem + "");

                            string nummatriculas = myReader.GetString(83);
                            var nummatricula = nummatriculas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nummatricula$$", "" + nummatricula + "");

                            string nomepaifuncs = myReader.GetString(2);
                            var nomepaifunc = nomepaifuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nomepaifunc$$", "" + nomepaifunc + "");

                            string nomemaefuncs = myReader.GetString(3);
                            var nomemaefunc = nomemaefuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nomemaefunc$$", "" + nomemaefunc + "");

                            string paifuncnacios = myReader.GetString(4);
                            var paifuncnacio = paifuncnacios.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$paifuncnacio$$", "" + paifuncnacio + "");

                            string maefuncnacios = myReader.GetString(5);
                            var maefuncnacio = maefuncnacios.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$maefuncnacio$$", "" + maefuncnacio + "");

                            DateTime datanascs = myReader.GetDateTime(6);
                            var datanasc = datanascs.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$datanasc$$", "" + datanasc + "");

                            string idades = myReader.GetString(88);
                            var idade = idades.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$idade$$", "" + idade + "");

                            string funcnacios = myReader.GetString(7);
                            var funcnacio = funcnacios.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$funcnacio$$", "" + funcnacio + "");

                            string estadocivils = myReader.GetString(8);
                            var estadocivil = estadocivils.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$estadocivil$$", "" + estadocivil + "");

                            string localnascs = myReader.GetString(9);
                            var localnasc = localnascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$localnasc$$", "" + localnasc + "");

                            string ufnascs = myReader.GetString(10);
                            var ufnasc = ufnascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$ufnasc$$", "" + ufnasc + "");

                            string rgs = myReader.GetString(11);
                            var rg = rgs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$rg$$", "" + rg + "");

                            string ctpssa = myReader.GetString(12);
                            var ctps = ctpssa.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$ctps$$", "" + ctps + "");

                            string ctpsss = myReader.GetString(13);
                            var ctpss = ctpsss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$ctpss$$", "" + ctpss + "");

                            string reservistas = myReader.GetString(14);
                            var reservista = reservistas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$reservista$$", "" + reservista + "");

                            string catreservistas = myReader.GetString(15);
                            var catreservista = catreservistas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$catreservista$$", "" + catreservista + "");

                            string cpfs = myReader.GetString(16);
                            var cpf = cpfs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$cpf$$", "" + cpf + "");

                            string tituloeleitors = myReader.GetString(17);
                            var tituloeleitor = tituloeleitors.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$tituloeleitor$$", "" + tituloeleitor + "");

                            string carteirasaudes = myReader.GetString(18);
                            var carteirasaude = carteirasaudes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$carteirasaude$$", "" + carteirasaude + "");

                            string cbos = myReader.GetString(19);
                            var cbo = cbos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$cbo$$", "" + cbo + "");

                            string cartmod19s = myReader.GetString(20);
                            var cartmod19 = cartmod19s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$cartmod19$$", "" + cartmod19 + "");

                            string casadobrasileiros = myReader.GetString(21);
                            var casadobrasileiro = casadobrasileiros.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$casadobrasileiro$$", "" + casadobrasileiro + "");

                            string naturalizados = myReader.GetString(22);
                            var naturalizado = naturalizados.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$naturalizado$$", "" + naturalizado + "");

                            string filhosbrasileiross = myReader.GetString(23);
                            var filhosbrasileiros = filhosbrasileiross.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$filhosbrasileiros$$", "" + filhosbrasileiros + "");

                            string datachegadabrasils = myReader.GetString(25);
                            var datachegadabrasil = datachegadabrasils.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$datachegadabrasil$$", "" + datachegadabrasil + "");

                            string nregistrogerals = myReader.GetString(26);
                            var nregistrogeral = nregistrogerals.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nregistrogeral$$", "" + nregistrogeral + "");

                            string nomeconjuges = myReader.GetString(27);
                            var nomeconjuge = nomeconjuges.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nomeconjuge$$", "" + nomeconjuge + "");

                            string quantosfilhoss = myReader.GetString(24);
                            var quantosfilhos = quantosfilhoss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$quantosfilhos$$", "" + quantosfilhos + "");

                            string enderecos = myReader.GetString(28);
                            var endereco = enderecos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$endereco$$", "" + endereco + "");

                            string mudancaenderecos = myReader.GetString(29);
                            var mudancaendereco = nregistrogerals.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$mudancaendereco$$", "" + mudancaendereco + "");

                            string corfuncs = myReader.GetString(70);
                            var corfunc = corfuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$corfunc$$", "" + corfunc + "");

                            string alturafuncs = myReader.GetString(71);
                            var alturafunc = alturafuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$alturafunc$$", "" + alturafunc + "");


                            string pesofuncs = myReader.GetString(72);
                            var pesofunc = pesofuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$pesofunc$$", "" + pesofunc + "");

                            string cabelosfuncs = myReader.GetString(73);
                            var cabelofunc = cabelosfuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$cabelosfunc$$", "" + cabelofunc + "");

                            string olhosfuncs = myReader.GetString(74);
                            var olhosfunc = olhosfuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$olhosfunc$$", "" + olhosfunc + "");

                            string sinaisfuncs = myReader.GetString(75);
                            var sinaisfunc = sinaisfuncs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$sinaisfunc$$", "" + sinaisfunc + "");


                            string dependente1s = myReader.GetString(30);
                            var dependente1 = dependente1s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente1$$", "" + dependente1 + "");

                            string dependente2s = myReader.GetString(33);
                            var dependente2 = dependente2s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente2$$", "" + dependente2 + "");

                            string dependente3s = myReader.GetString(36);
                            var dependente3 = dependente3s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente3$$", "" + dependente3 + "");

                            string dependente4s = myReader.GetString(39);
                            var dependente4 = dependente4s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente4$$", "" + dependente4 + "");

                            string dependente5s = myReader.GetString(42);
                            var dependente5 = dependente5s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente5$$", "" + dependente5 + "");


                            string dependente6s = myReader.GetString(45);
                            var dependente6 = dependente6s.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente6$$", "" + dependente6 + "");

                            string dependente1parentes = myReader.GetString(31);
                            var depentende1parente = dependente1parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente1parente$$", "" + depentende1parente + "");

                            string dependente2parentes = myReader.GetString(34);
                            var dependente2parente = dependente2parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente2parente$$", "" + dependente2parente + "");

                            string dependente3parentes = myReader.GetString(37);
                            var dependente3parente = dependente3parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente3parente$$", "" + dependente3parente + "");

                            string dependente4parentes = myReader.GetString(40);
                            var dependente4parente = dependente4parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente4parente$$", "" + dependente4parente + "");

                            string dependente5parentes = myReader.GetString(43);
                            var dependente5parente = dependente5parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente5parente$$", "" + dependente5parente + "");

                            string dependente6parentes = myReader.GetString(46);
                            var dependente6parente = dependente6parentes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente6parente$$", "" + dependente6parente + "");

                            string dependente1nascs = myReader.GetString(32);
                            var dependente1nasc = dependente1nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente1nasc$$", "" + dependente1nasc + "");

                            string dependente2nascs = myReader.GetString(35);
                            var dependente2nasc = dependente2nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente2nasc$$", "" + dependente2nasc + "");

                            string dependente3nascs = myReader.GetString(38);
                            var dependente3nasc = dependente3nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente3nasc$$", "" + dependente3nasc + "");

                            string dependente4nascs = myReader.GetString(41);
                            var dependente4nasc = dependente4nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente4nasc$$", "" + dependente4nasc + "");

                            string dependente5nascs = myReader.GetString(44);
                            var dependente5nasc = dependente5nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente5nasc$$", "" + dependente5nasc + "");

                            string dependente6nascs = myReader.GetString(47);
                            var dependente6nasc = dependente6nascs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dependente6nasc$$", "" + dependente6nasc + "");

                            string datacadpiss = myReader.GetString(48);
                            var datacadpis = datacadpiss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$datacadpis$$", "" + datacadpis + "");

                            string piss = myReader.GetString(49);
                            var pis = piss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$pis$$", "" + pis + "");

                            string nobancopiss = myReader.GetString(50);
                            var nobancopis = nobancopiss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$nobancopis$$", "" + nobancopis + "");

                            string endpiss = myReader.GetString(51);
                            var endpis = endpiss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$endpis$$", "" + endpis + "");

                            string bancopiss = myReader.GetString(52);
                            var bancopis = bancopiss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$bancopis$$", "" + bancopis + "");

                            string agpiss = myReader.GetString(53);
                            var agpis = agpiss.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$agpis$$", "" + agpis + "");

                            DateTime dataentradas = myReader.GetDateTime(54);
                            var dataentrada = dataentradas.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dataentrada$$", "" + dataentrada + "");

                            DateTime dataentradalongas = myReader.GetDateTime(54);
                            var dataentradalonga = dataentradalongas.ToLongDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dataentradalonga$$", "" + dataentradalonga + "");

                            DateTime dataregs = myReader.GetDateTime(55);
                            var datareg = dataregs.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$datareg$$", "" + datareg + "");

                            string ocupacaos = myReader.GetString(56);
                            var ocupacao = ocupacaos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$ocupacao$$", "" + ocupacao + "");

                            string secaos = myReader.GetString(57);
                            var secao = secaos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$secao$$", "" + secao + "");

                            string salarioinicials = myReader.GetString(58);
                            var salarioinicial = salarioinicials.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$salarioinicial$$", "" + salarioinicial + "");

                            string comissoess = myReader.GetString(59);
                            var comissoes = comissoess.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$comissoes$$", "" + comissoes + "");

                            string tarefas = myReader.GetString(60);
                            var tarefa = tarefas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$tarefa$$", "" + tarefa + "");

                            string formapagamentos = myReader.GetString(61);
                            var formapagamento = formapagamentos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$formapagamento$$", "" + formapagamento + "");

                            string eoptantes = myReader.GetString(62);
                            var eoptante = eoptantes.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$eoptante$$", "" + eoptante + "");

                            DateTime dataopcaos = myReader.GetDateTime(63);
                            var dataopcao = dataopcaos.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dataopcao$$", "" + dataopcao + "");

                            DateTime dataretratacaos = myReader.GetDateTime(64);
                            var dataretratacao = dataretratacaos.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dataretratacao$$", "" + dataretratacao + "");

                            string bancodepositarios = myReader.GetString(69);
                            var bancodepositario = bancodepositarios.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$bancodepositario$$", "" + bancodepositario + "");

                            string hentradas = myReader.GetString(65);
                            var hentrada = hentradas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$hentrada$$", "" + hentrada + "");


                            string halmocos = myReader.GetString(66);
                            var halmoco = halmocos.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$halmoco$$", "" + halmoco + "");


                            string hsaidas = myReader.GetString(67);
                            var hsaida = hsaidas.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$hsaida$$", "" + hsaida + "");


                            string dsrs = myReader.GetString(68);
                            var dsr = dsrs.ToString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$dsr$$", "" + dsr + "");

                            DateTime datafimcontratos = myReader.GetDateTime(78);
                            var datafimcontrato = datafimcontratos.ToShortDateString();
                            document.ReplaceText("$$datafimcontrato$$", "" + datafimcontrato + "");
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }



                    document.SaveAs(OutputFile);
                    MessageBox.Show("Ficha de Registro de "+vIDg2+" criada com sucesso!", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

                } // Release this document from memory.


            }
        }
        else
        {

        }





    }
```

Thank you for your help and for sake of simplicity, I believe we should better spread the word about DocX, because honestly a newbie like myself, if knew before about it, would not have lost lots of time with interop.

PS: If you face problems where sometimes your Word Interop Works or not, and / or when trying to use interop the app crashes, this is the way to go.